# Powershell window title "shortening" algorithm when used in Windows Terminal, where is it?

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I want to change the tab title of Powershell tabs in Windows Terminal because I think they must be slightly wrong or at least a bit confusing.

If I'm deep in a folder structure, it shows something like this:

```
C:\...\Roaming\Microsoft
```

Which is good. However, if I'm not deep in a folder structure, like say in the users directory, it shows this:

```
C:\...\C:\Users
```

Which makes no sense, as "C:\Users" is not a sub-folder of C:\. Where exactly is this algorithm, or setting, stored, so that I can attempt to fix it? Or is this a bug in some script so I can report it to Microsoft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by some add-in that you have installed.

By default the title is only the name of the shell, for example "Windows PowerShell".

Changing the title is described in the Microsoft article
[Tutorial: Configure tab titles in Windows Terminal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/tab-title).

For PowerShell, the command used is:

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "New Title"
```

For example:

[image]

You need to find which software you have installed is changing the tab title.
This can even be a clever
[prompt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7.1)
that you have defined.

Comment: I have Oh-My-Posh, must be it that messes it up then.

Comment: Gah, I updated oh-my-posh and it broke everything. It was the culprit though.